# How can I use date objects as tick labels for a linear axis?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have tried using the d3 time axis and yes, this problem is resolved by using the d3 time axis but there are lots of other complications I am not able to handle. The linear axis on the other hand seems to only present the issue of tick labels.

I have an array full of date objects for my tick labels - dateTickValues

```
console.log(dateTickValues)
```

returns

```
Thu Jan 01 2015 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (IST),Fri Jan 02 2015 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (IST),Sat Jan 03 2015 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (IST),Sun Jan 04 2015 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (IST),Mon Jan 05 2015 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (IST),Tue Jan 06 2015 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (IST)
```

but when I use

```
var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
.domain([0, no_of_ticks])
.range([0, width]);


var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(xScale)
.ticks(no_of_ticks) //computed elsewhere in the code - clean
.tickValues(dateTickValues)
.orient("top");
```

the tick labels on the resulting graph are empty - that is no tick labels appear.

Why does this happen and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is using the [`.tickFormat()` function](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes#tickFormat). It's not clear to me what you're actually trying to do, so here are two versions.

First, you can use the `Date` objects themselves with the scale, then `.tickFormat()` is something like

```
.tickFormat(function(d) { return d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")(new Date(d)); });
```

Complete demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7ho5srcb/).

If you're using the index into an array of dates with the scale, it would be something like

```
.tickFormat(function(d, i) { return d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")(new Date(dates[i])); });
```

Complete demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7ho5srcb/1/).

On a separate note, it doesn't make sense to use `.ticks()` and `.tickValues()` at the same time -- you probably want only `.tickValues()`.

Comment: Ok, interestingly - if I don't use tickValues() at all but use tickFormat() and format the elements in my dateTickValues array as required, everything works like a charm. Thanks a lot, Lars!